# Como guardar la info en Mysql desde laravel que me traigo de Api techo

Tags: laravel, api

Tengo una aplicacion que le pega a la api de techo.org. Basicamente se traen las ciudades de Argentina y sus ciudades/barrios.
Yo quisiera que eso se guardara en mi DB mysql.

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Cuando registro una propiedad en mi aplicacion queda todo guardado salvo lo de api techo.

```
// Declaro las variables
var mySelect, btnEnviar, paisSeleccionado, registrar, errores, expRegMail,str;
var nombre,apellido,email,contrasena,repcontrasena,dni,sexo,nacimiento,celular,provinciaElegida,sedeElegida,ciudadElegida;

//Ejectuto código una vez que se cargó el HTML
window.onload = function() {
    btnPropiedades = document.getElementById('editar-propiedad');
    btnPropiedades.addEventListener('click', function () {
        //Guardo el botón enviar en una variable
        // btnEnviar = document.getElementById('enviar');
        registrar = document.getElementById('registrar');
        //LLamada Ajax
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://pilote.techo.org/admin/?do=api.getPaises", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        //Llamo a las funciones
        pedirProvincias();

    function pedirProvincias() {
        //Hago llamado de Ajax para pedir provincias
        //funciona como el primer llamado
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var misProvincias = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                misProvincias = misProvincias.contenido;
                //console.log(misProvincias);
                var selectProvincias = document.querySelectorAll('#provincias');
                for (provincia in misProvincias) {
                    selectProvincias[0].innerHTML += "<option value='" + misProvincias[provincia] + "'>" + provincia + "</option>";
                }
                //Una vez que termino de cargar el select,
                //Llamo a la funcion para pedir las ciudades de esta provincia
                console.log(selectProvincias);
                pedirCiudades();
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://pilote.techo.org/admin/?do=api.getRegiones?idPais=1", true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }


//Esta función tiene el mismo comportamiento que la anterior
function pedirCiudades(){

  var provinciaSeleccionada = document.querySelectorAll('#provincias')[0].value;

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      var misCiudades = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      misCiudades = misCiudades.contenido;
      //console.log(misCiudades);
      var selectCiudades = document.querySelectorAll('#ciudades');
      console.log(selectCiudades);
      selectCiudades[0].innerHTML = "";
      for(ciudad in misCiudades){
        selectCiudades[0].innerHTML += "<option value='"+misCiudades[ciudad]+"'>"+ciudad+"</option>";
      }
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://pilote.techo.org/admin/?do=api.getCiudades?idRegionLT="+provinciaSeleccionada, true);

  xmlhttp.send();
}
    });//termina addEventListener
//Mismo comportamiento
}
function cambiarCiudad() {

   pedirCiudades();

//Esta función tiene el mismo comportamiento que la anterior
    function pedirCiudades(){

        var provinciaSeleccionada = document.querySelectorAll('#provincias')[0].value;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                var misCiudades = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                misCiudades = misCiudades.contenido;
                //console.log(misCiudades);
                var selectCiudades = document.querySelectorAll('#ciudades');
                console.log(selectCiudades);
                selectCiudades[0].innerHTML = "";
                for(ciudad in misCiudades){
                    selectCiudades[0].innerHTML += "<option value='"+misCiudades[ciudad]+"'>"+ciudad+"</option>";
                }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://pilote.techo.org/admin/?do=api.getCiudades?idRegionLT="+provinciaSeleccionada, true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function init() {
    var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

> Propiedad model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Propiedad extends Model{

    protected $table = 'Propiedades';

    protected $fillable = [
        'titulo',
        'descripcion',
        'ubicacion',
        'tipoInmueble',
        'tipoPublicacion',
        'antiguedad',
        'dormitorios',
        'cocheras',
        'banios',
        'toilette',
        'valorPropiedad',
        'provincia',
        'ciudad',
        'superficie'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

> PropiedadesTable

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class PropiedadesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('propiedades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('titulo');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->string('ubicacion');
            $table->string('tipoInmueble');
            $table->string('tipoPublicacion');
            $table->integer('antiguedad');
            $table->integer('dormitorios');
            $table->integer('cocheras')->nullable();
            $table->integer('banios');
            $table->integer('toilette')->nullable();
            $table->integer('valorPropiedad');
            $table->string('provincia');
            $table->string('ciudad');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('superficie');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('propiedades');
    }
}
```

> PropiedadController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Propiedad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PropiedadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request){
        $propiedades = Propiedad::where('user_id', $request->user()->id);
        return view ('Profile.ver-propiedades', [
            'propiedades' => $propiedades
        ]);
    }

    public function mostrarPropiedades(){
        $propiedades = Propiedad::all();
        return view('home');
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('Profile.agregarPropiedad');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->propiedades()->create($request->all());
        return redirect('profile#propiedades');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return redirect('profile#propiedades');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function verPropiedadesUsuario(Request $request){
        $props = Propiedad::where('user_id', $request->get('user_id'))->get();
        return view('Profile/ver-propiedades', ['propiedades' => $props]);
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Lo otro ya guarda TODO solo me falta lo que me traigo por la api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta parte de JavaScript no nos muestra mucho, sería mejor ver como estás pasando (y recibiendo) los datos a los controladores y como estás manejando dicha información.

Comment: @Shaz ahi resubi

Comment: ¿En qué formato la API te entrega la información? o sea, un `dump($request->all)` en el método store() del controlador.